# Linux perf to measure memory bandwidth on AMD EPYC 2nd Gen

Tags: performance, mpi, perf, amd-processor, memory-bandwidth

How could I measure the memory bandwidth of an application using `perf` and `mpirun`? I would like to know if this application is memory bandwidth bound.

Comment: My suggestion would be to take an experimental approach and look at how performance varies with the allocation of MPI processes to physical CPU cores. You can normally control this using (implementation-specific) arguments to mpirun. If, for example, your CPU has 4 NUMA regions each of 16 cores then run a 16 process program in two configurations: first, all processes in the first NUMA region (probably cores 0-15); second, processes distributed evenly with 4 per NUMA region. If there is a significant difference in performance (i.e all on one NUMA region is very slow) then you're memory limited.

Comment: I think you should combine mpirun of your application and some system-wide hw counters monitoring. AMD's own tool uProf https://developer.amd.com/amd-uprof/ has some variants to monitor memory bandwidth; there is also some basic memory bw tests like STREAM described in http://developer.amd.com/wp-content/resources/56420.pdf. For uProf: `AMDuProfPcm-m memory -a ...` from https://developer.amd.com/wordpress/media/files/AMDuprof_Resources/User_Guide_AMD_uProf_v3.4_GA.pdf pages 26-28, 37, 39 and other. Not sure how to set up `perf stat -a -I 10000 -e ...` for memory bw monitoring on EPYC 2nd.